# Gmaps4rails get marker detail when click on particular marker on map in ruby on rails4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

**Hey i am looking for get vnote_id from marker parameter.Now i always get last vnote_id of all marker when i click on particular marker on map**

i can not access here marker.vnote_id only i can access marker.title

#### Controller Code

```
@vnote_hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@vnote) do |vnote, marker|
marker.lat vnote.latitude
marker.lng vnote.longitude
marker.title vnote.id.to_s
marker.json({vnote_id: vnote.id })
```

#### View Code

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google'); 

handler.buildMap({ provider: { minZoom: 3, maxZoom: 200,zoom: 5,scrollwheel: false }, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
        var marker, _i, _len;
        markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @vnote_hash.to_json %>);
        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();
        for (_i = 0, _len = markers.length; _i < _len; _i++) {

            marker = markers[_i];

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click', function(evt) {

                $.get('http://localhost:3000/vnote/popup_vnote_info', { vnote_id: marker.getServiceObject().title });


                return console.log(handler.getMap().getBounds().getNorthEast().toString());

            });             
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all your json is in `<%=raw @vnote_hash.to_json %>`

So:

```
var raw_json = <%=raw @vnote_hash.to_json %>;
markers = handler.addMarkers(raw_json);
```

And in your loop:

```
raw_json[i].vnote_id
```

An alternative is to merge object properties so you only use one object.

Comment: Hey brother many many many thanx,this is work for me like magic,Thank you sooooooooooo much.

Comment: Hello apneadiving, could you please view the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748320/gmaps4rails-looping-through-arrayI was attempting to dynamically create an array of lat/lng and pass it into the gem but had no luck in getting it to work