# Gmaps4rails looping through array

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, gmaps4rails

I have an array with 30+ locations I would like to display on my map. However, I have not found one source that demonstrates how to iterate through an array so that the markers appear on a map, but instead opt to strictly hard code the map lat/long values.

For example, this is the code I have at present but it returns errors:

```
  allLocations = root.table.rows().data()
  root.forMap = []
  for aLocation in allLocations
    root.forMap.push(aLocation[9] + ', ' + aLocation[10])

  $('#multi_markers').map ->
    handler = Gmaps.build("Google")
    handler.buildMap
      internal:
        id: "multi_markers"
    , ->
    markers = handler.addMarkers(root.forMap)
    handler.bounds.extendWith markers
    handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

*Note: I cannot simply use the ruby methods because the table must also interact with DataTable data within the .js.coffee file.*

How can I loop through the array within the gmaps4rails method?

Answer (score -1):

Since `handler.addMarkers` takes an array why not just use jQuery.map and build an array of markers beforehand?

```
all_locations = $.map root.table.rows().data(), (row)->
   return {
     lat: row[9],
     lng: row[10]
   }

$('#multi_markers').map ->
    handler = Gmaps.build("Google")
    handler.buildMap
      internal:
        id: "multi_markers"
    , ->
    markers = handler.addMarkers(allLocations)
    handler.bounds.extendWith markers
    handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

Comment: I suck at coffeescript - so this might not work straight off the bat but you should get the general idea.

Comment: Did you read the readme on https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails ?

Comment: But I need to do this in CoffeeScript in the js.coffee file because the maps will dynamically interact with a datatable

Comment: How can I get all of them, not just the first one but all 30, the array for them is two dimensional where the second dimension is the  lat/long vlaues

Comment: Want to take this to a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64276/discussion-between-sauron-and-papirtiger).

Comment: Sorry don´t have time.

Comment: I'm going to switch to the native Gmaps as this gmaps4rails is WAY too limiting for what I need to do. Thanks for the attempted help